# WPF Datagrid bind data list to a template column combobox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've been searching for hours on how to bind data to combobox in a datagrid template column. I found some in the site but nothing seems to work. Here's what I've done so far:

```
public partial class CashReceipt : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<CashItem> itemsList;
        private ObservableCollection<string> accounts;
        public CashReceipt()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            itemsList = new ObservableCollection<CashItem>();
            accounts = new ObservableCollection<string>()
            {
                "5710",
                "6010",
                "6510",
                "7010"
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                CashItem item = new CashItem();
                itemsList.Add(item);
            }

            clDatagrid.ItemsSource = itemsList;
        }
    }

    public struct CashItem
    {
        public string account { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public decimal amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The XAML is

```
<UserControl x:Class="CashLedgerApp.CashReceipt"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CashLedgerApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             MinHeight="320" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="AccountsList" Source="{Binding Path=accounts}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border Margin="100,20" BorderBrush="gray" BorderThickness="0.5">
        <Grid Background="White">
            <DataGrid x:Name="clDatagrid" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="30" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="True">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <!--<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="clAccount" Header="Compte No" Width="1*" SelectedValuePath="{Binding account}" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=account}"/>-->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Compte No" Width="1*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AccountsList}}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding account}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="account"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding description}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Montant" Width="1.5*" Binding="{Binding amount}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

When I execute this program, the combobox in the template column is always empty. The data in the **accounts** list is just a sample to make things work. I'll use data from database in the final version of the code. But I need to make it work first.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I made changes as you suggested @ASh, here is the C# and XAML (I added some data to the **itemList** collection, as expected, those data are displayed in the grid but the `ComboBox` in the `DataGridTemplateColumn` are still empty):

```
public partial class CashReceipt : UserControl
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CashItem> itemsList;
        public ObservableCollection<string> Accounts;
        public CashReceipt()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            itemsList = new ObservableCollection<CashItem>();
            Accounts = new ObservableCollection<string>()
            {
                "5710",
                "6010",
                "6510",
                "7010"
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                CashItem item = new CashItem();
                item.description = "Achats";
                item.amount = 250000;
                itemsList.Add(item);
            }

            clDatagrid.ItemsSource = itemsList;
        }
    }

    public struct CashItem
    {
        public string account { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public decimal amount { get; set; }
    }

<UserControl x:Class="CashLedgerApp.CashReceipt"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CashLedgerApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             MinHeight="320" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="AccountsList" Source="{Binding Path=Accounts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border Margin="100,20" BorderBrush="gray" BorderThickness="0.5">
        <Grid Background="White">
            <DataGrid x:Name="clDatagrid" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="8" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="30" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="True">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Compte No" Width="1*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AccountsList}}"
                                          SelectedItem="{Binding account}"
                                          DisplayMemberPath="account"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding description}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Montant" Width="1.5*" Binding="{Binding amount}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

I might have missed something I think but can't figure out what.

Comment: `public ObservableCollection<string> Accounts;` - you are still missing getter and setter: `public ObservableCollection<string> Accounts { get; private set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding `{Binding Path=accounts}` will work if you make `accounts` a public property (currently it is a private field)

```
public ObservableCollection<string> accounts { get; private set; }
```

also naming conventions suggest it should become `Accounts` (and `{Binding Path=Accounts}`)

additionally simple Binding searches properties in DataContext, but in your case Accounts is a property of UserControl itself, so it is necessary to change source of Binding:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="AccountsList" 
                      Source="{Binding Path=Accounts, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Comment: Hello, I changed ''accounts'' to ''Accounts'' and made it public. But nothing changed. I also changed it in the "Binding"

Comment: @Patrik, I added details